# vector pattern matching and vector replacement in list of files names in R

Tags: r, vector, replace, pattern-matching, gsub

I have 60 ".tif" files in a folder. They are named as follow: a_1, a_2, a_3,...,a_30 b_1,  b_2, b_3,...,b_30 etc.

I would like to change the numeric values by date.
For example, a_1 and b_1 will be renamed by a_2010-01-01 and b_2010-01-01, respectively and a_2 and b_2 will be renamed by a_2010-01-02 and b_2010-01-02, etc.

I created two vectors:

```
file_name<-list.files("/path/", pattern="tif", recursive=F)
d<-seq(1, 100, 1)
day <- seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), to= as.Date("2010-01-30"), by='day')
```

I tried to use the function gsub but I do not really understand how to use it:

```
 gsub(d, day, file_name)
```

I am very new in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in many ways, here is a comprehensible one:

```
library(data.table)
file_name<-list.files("/path/", pattern="tif", recursive=F)
day <- seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), to= as.Date("2010-01-30"), by='day')

for(i in 1:30){
  oldFiles = file_name[file_name %like% paste0("_",i)]
  cat("Handling", oldFiles, "\n")
  newFiles = gsub(paste0("_", i), paste0("_", as.character(day[i])), oldFiles)
  file.rename(from = file.path("/path", oldFiles),to = file.path("/path", newFiles))
}
```

Make sure you have changed the "/path" to your files' directory and do a backup before running the above code, since it is written blindly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to apply your code but I got the following error message:     Error in file_name %like% paste0("_", i) : 
  could not find function "%like%"

Comment: This is not very "r"-ic. `file.rename()` is vectorized. There is no need to wrap it in a loop. Just execute it with a character vector of old names as the `from` argument and a character vector of the new names as the `to` argument.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that you're not approaching this as a `gsub` problem. You're on the right track there, as I don't think you want to use `gsub`.  You've created a date vector, now you just have to prepend it with `"a_"`and `"b"`.  `file.rename()` is what you want to use to rename the files. Trying to pattern match while renaming the files is more pain than it's worth.  Just create the vector and rename:

```
old_names <- list.files(pattern="tif", recursive=F)
days <- seq(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2010-01-30"), by = "day")
new_names <- paste(paste(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 30), days, sep = "_"), "tif", sep = ".")
file.rename(from = old_names, to = new_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `strsplit` with `sapply` as:

```
# Represents sample files from directory
v <- c('a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3','a_30', 'b_1', 'b_2', 'b_3','b_30')

sapply(strsplit(v, split = "_"), function(x){
  sprintf("%s_%s-%02d",x[1],"2010-01", as.numeric(x[2]))
})

#[1] "a_2010-01-01" "a_2010-01-02" "a_2010-01-03" "a_2010-01-30" "b_2010-01-01"
#      "b_2010-01-02" "b_2010-01-03" "b_2010-01-30"
```